# Determine the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded between $y = x^2$ and $y = x$ about $y = x.$

Tags: integration

I wrote this problem a while ago and solved it using a geometric argument, instead of using coordinate transformation.

Here is how I approached this problem:

Notice that the radius of a circular segment has radius,
$ r = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(x - x^2)$. So the volume is given as: 
$V = \int_0^1\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(x - x^2)\right]^2 \pi dx = \frac{\pi}{60}$.

Is this correct? If it is wrong, how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We operate very informally. The radius "at" $x$ is right. If we look at the part from $x$ to $x+dx$, that gives us a ham slice of thickness $\sqrt{2}\,dx$. "Add up" (integrate). The volume is
$$\int_{x=0}^1 \pi\sqrt{2}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-x^2)\right]^2\,dx.$$

Comment: Thank you, it crossed my mind a couple times. Could you please suggest a way to formalize it?

Comment: One can use the technique you rejected, rotate the region.  Or else imagine dividing the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ into $n$ equally spaced subintervals, compute the  radius when we are $w$ from the origin along that line. We get a Riemann sum which translates to an integral from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You are welcome. I used the physicist's/engineer's way of setting up an integral!